# Using formatting option 'aligned' in 'to_dms' function in QGIS 3.4.2

Tags: qgis-3, expression, degrees-minutes-seconds

Using formatting option `'aligned'` in the expression:

```
to_dms(x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:32632','EPSG:4230')), 'x', 2, 'aligned')
```

not only is the alignment of degrees, minutes, seconds as expected, but also the suffix E (which should be added with the 'suffix' format option) is added.

Is there a way to eliminate the suffix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr` to remove the final character of the string (the N, S, E or W):

```
substr(
to_dms(x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:32632','EPSG:4230')), 'x', 2, 'aligned'),
1, -1)
```

will return the dms coordinates from the first to the second last character.